# Можно ли в гугл-таблицах сделать подсказки с привязкой к заливке ячейки?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Можно ли в гугл-таблицах сделать подсказки с привязкой к заливке ячейки? Чтобы не назначать каждый раз вручную. Чтото типа:

```
if (cellBackgroundColor === green) {
    add.tooltip('this is green');
}
```

Comment: Цвета же постоянно будут меняться. Вы предлагаете менять и все заметки? Может быть вы просто введете пояснительную записку к обозначениям?

Comment: contributorpw, Вы кажется меня не так поняли. Текст подсказки не связан с цветом прям, то есть в подсказке может быть написано "Lorem ipsum" или "это правильный ответ", суть не в том чтобы передать цвет в текст подсказки, а чтобы просто привязать определенный текст к определенному цвету заливки ячейки.

Comment: Например, я обновляю заметку - меняется цвет заливки?

Comment: Нет, скорее наоборот - есть скажем 4 базовых цвета - синий, зеленый, красный и желтый. К каждому из этих цветов привязана своя заметка. Я крашу ячейку в зеленый - на ней появляется заметка соответствующая зеленой заливке, в красный - там своя. В обратную сторону это работать не должно, то есть в эту сторону думать не надо. Просто при заливке в определенный цвет должна привязываться определенная подсказка

Answer (score 1):

Основная идея в том, чтобы перебрать все цвета и переназначить все заметки адресно. Другого способа пока нет.

```js
  var dic = {
    '#ff0000': 'Hello!', // red
    '#ffff00': 'OK' // yellow
  };

  range.setNotes(
    range.getNotes().map(function(row, i) {
      return row.map(function(_, j) {
        if (dic[colors[i][j]]) return dic[colors[i][j]];
        return '';
      });
    })
  )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Событие на изменение цвета отрабатывается безадресно, т.е. вы не знаете даже имени листа, на котором произошло изменение, поэтому триггер события `CHANGE` тут бесполезен. Придется либо запускать по таймеру, либо из меню.

Полный пример тут [Обновить закрашенные заметки](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/spreadsheet_update-colored-notes)

Comment: Не согласен с тем, что "триггер события CHANGE тут бесполезен". Как раз с ним и надо работать (когда свойство event.changeType=="FORMAT"). Да, лишние срабатывания могут случиться - вреда никакого. Зато нужные не будут пропущены.

Comment: С удовольсвием обсужу этот вопрос https://t.me/googleappsscriptrc

Comment: Автор, пример недостаточно хорош?

Comment: @frigoris, не то?